# How to build a docker image from jenkins agent running on kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, aks

I tried below pipeline code to check whether docker commands work first but failing.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml """
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: jenkins-agent
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: jnlp
          image: 'jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest'
          args: ['${JENKINS_SECRET}', '${JENKINS_AGENT_NAME}']
          env:
          - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: aws-credentials
                key: accessKeyId
          - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: aws-credentials
                key: secretAccessKey
          - name: AWS_REGION
            value: us-east-1
          volumeMounts:
          - name: docker-sock
            mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
        volumes:
        - name: docker-sock
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
      """
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
    }
  }
    environment {
        AWS_REGION = credentials('my-aws-region')
        ENVIRONMENT = 'dev'
        LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME = 'my-lambda-function'
    }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'python -m unittest discover tests'
        }
    }
    stage('Package') {
      steps {
        sh 'mkdir package'
        sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt -t package'
        sh 'cp lambda_function.py package/'
        sh 'cp -r tests/ package/'
        sh 'cd package && zip -r9 ../function.zip .'
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
        environment {
            TF_VAR_aws_region = "${AWS_REGION}"
            TF_VAR_environment = "${ENVIRONMENT}"
            TF_VAR_lambda_function_name = "${LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME}"
        }
        steps {
            sh 'terraform init'
            sh 'terraform plan'
            sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve'
        }
    }
  }

  post {
    always {
      cleanWs()
    }
  }
}
```

Error I got:

```
Error when executing always post condition:
hudson.AbortException: Attempted to execute a step that requires a node context while ‘agent none’ was specified. Be sure to specify your own ‘node { ... }’ blocks when using ‘agent none’.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ErrorStep$Execution.run(ErrorStep.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ErrorStep$Execution.run(ErrorStep.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousStepExecution.start(SynchronousStepExecution.java:37)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:322)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:399)
```

So I removed the post section and tried.
this time got this.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JENKINS_SECRET for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at
```

I heard that JENKINS_SECRET  is auto generated but getting this error.

So, tried a different code but getting error as no docker daemon this time.

```
podTemplate(containers: [
    containerTemplate(
        name: 'maven', 
        image: 'maven:3.8.1-jdk-8', 
        command: 'sleep', 
        args: '30d'
        ),
    containerTemplate(
        name: 'docker', 
        image: 'docker:latest', 
        command: 'sleep', 
        args: '30d')
  ]) {

    node(POD_LABEL) {
        stage('Get a Maven project') {
            git url: 'https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git', branch: 'main'
            container('maven') {
                stage('Build a Maven project') {
                    sh '''
                    echo "maven build"
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Get a docker Project') {
            git url: 'https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform.git', branch: 'main'
            container('docker') {
                stage('Build a Go project') {
                    sh '''
                    echo "Go Build"
                    docker --version
                    docker ps -a
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Error I got:

```
+ docker --version
Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
+ docker ps -a
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I changed my pipleine and tried with below one.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            label 'kubeagent'
            defaultContainer 'kube-agent'
            yaml """
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: Pod
            metadata:
              labels:
                app: my-docker-build
            spec:
              containers:
              - name: docker
                image: jpetazzo/dind:latest
                command: ["cat"]
                tty: true
              volumes:
              - name: docker-sock
                hostPath:
                  path: /var/run/docker.sock
              - name: my-repo
                gitRepo:
                  repository: https://github.com/my/repo.git
            """
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage( 'docker start starting' ){
            steps {
                container('docker') {
                    sh 'hostname'
                    sh 'sleep 50'
                    sh 'docker --version'
                    sh 'curl -o Dockerfile https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ukreddy-erwin/jenkins_custom_image/ukreddy-erwin-patch-1/Dockerfile'
                    sh 'docker build -t jenkins:test .'
                    sh 'docker image ls'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test Docker Image') {
            steps {
                container('docker') {
                sh 'hostname'
                sh 'sleep 50'
                sh 'docker --version'
                sh 'docker build -t my-docker-image:latest .'
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Push Docker Image') {
            steps {
                sh 'hostname'
                sh 'docker push my-docker-image:latest'
            }
    }
}
}
```

But this failing with error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: container docker not found in pod kube-agent-gc6rw
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.validateOrDefaultContainerId(PodOperationsImpl.java:344)
```

So, I added the container image docker spec in kubernetes plugin screen manage nodes/configure clouds/kubernetes type area and ran without specification here in pipeline. It worked and able to run docker images ls,docker ps commands.
But when I try docker build, I am getting errors as apt,yum repo mirrors unable to connect even for yum update commands in dockerfile.

dockerfile

```
FROM amd64/amazonlinux:2
RUN yum -y update
```

Error details:

```
root@kube-agent-mgjsl:/home/jenkins/agent# docker build -t jenkins:test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  20.77MB
Step 1/6 : FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
 ---> f16216f97fcb
Step 2/6 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4563ef4109a2
Step 3/6 : RUN apt update && apt install -y wget
 ---> Running in 4e3756cd5298

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Err:1 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'packagecloud.io'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packagecloud.io'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package wget
The command '/bin/sh -c apt update && apt install -y wget' returned a non-zero code: 100
root@kube-agent-mgjsl:/home/jenkins/agent#
```

Comment: on the second example, try to define a container using docker dind, this container will have docker running inside or you could install docker on the host and export the socker to your container where you want to build the image

Comment: thank you, tried that one and got stuck in next stage, can you see the details updated in the question now and share your thoughts

Comment: sorry for the external link, but this could help, you don't need to define the k8s agent https://joostvdg.github.io/jenkins-pipeline/podtemplate-dind/